# IOException Concurrent timeout inputStream read HTTP request

Tags: java, glassfish, jax-rs, httprequest, vert.x

Using vertx-web-client to make a POST call to a web service deployed in glassfish I was getting IOException

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read(TemporarySelectorReader.java:126)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read(TemporarySelectorReader.java:75)
```

But using Postman with the same body everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

What was happening was that the web-client was using chunked transfer encoding(chunk streaming).
according to [vert.x Documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-client/js/)

> When you know the size of the stream, you shall specify before using the content-length header ... 
>   `.putHeader("content-length", fileLen)`

and thus

> The POST will **not** be chunked.